# view controller does not load with content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a button that when clicked shows a view controller. The code for that event is:

[image]

and my view controller looks like this:

[image]

note the segmented control and background image.

Here is my h and m files of my view controller in case you need them:

[image]

when I run my app here is how that view control looks on my iPad:

[image]

why do the background image and segmented control do not appear? why are contents not being loaded? It looks like another view controller is being loaded but I have already make sure that I am placing the correct name in the string for the view controller.

---

```
    - (IBAction) vaClick
{
    imgVa.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bt-valores.png"];

UIViewController *control = [[NuestrosValoresViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NuestrosValoresViewController"
                                                                            bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc]
initWithRootViewController:control];

[self presentModalViewController:navControl animated:NO];

[navControl setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

[control release];
[navControl release];


//UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc]
//initWithRootViewController:control];
//[self presentModalViewController:navControl animated:NO];
```

}

should I release it like this? sorry I basically have to translate a power point presentation to an app therefore I know very little about objective-c. thanks for the help and sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Please do not take screenshots of your code. Rather copy and paste it and format it as code (using back tick or the {}'s at the top of the entry field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the root view controller of your UINavigationController.

Use this line instead when initializing the navigation controller:

`UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:control];`

You'll also want to release `navControl` after you present it modally. I'll write out the code for you if you post your code instead of using screenshots.